# I dont know how I can save project to ipa

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

Thank you
I learned a lot from this site
I have a question
I finished the application is running
webview
But I remain one step keeping the program
And send it to the iPhone to try it on two ipa
I want to save formulas ipa
Thank you

Comment: Could the next thing u learn please be, how to use a dot (.) in english language?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just save an app as an IPA. Only if you submit it to the app store with a proper developer's license will they then distribute it in the store in that format

Answer (score 0):

Running "Build and Archive" from the Build menu in Xcode will create an ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

Stepwise Procedure to create an IPA file,

1.First of all,choose your device as IOS Device in Scheme near Breakpoint tab in Xcode.

2.In Xcode menu,Product->Clean and build your application.

3.If the provisioning certificate is not valid,it will lead to build failed with an error.If so you have to change it to a valid certificate through your project->build settings.Else if build succeeded just leave this step.

4.Then select Product->archive,it will create an archive file in Organiser->archives and open it up for you after archive finished.

5.choose share tab in Organiser followed by contents->.ipa and Identity->choose your valid distribution certificate and click next.

6.within a minute it will ask name for your IPA file to save.Give a name and save it in Desktop.

7.Open iTunes and drag and drop your IPA file in Library->Apps.

8.Now connect and select your Device in itunes->choose apps tab under it and sync your app ipa to the Device.It will install your IPA file to the device.

9.Thats all.Now you can run your App IPA file in your device.